# Storing variables in a list when not initially assigned in python

Tags: python, list, store

Good afternoon. 
I created an empty list that Is going to be filled by the user. I used an infinite loop to continuously ask the user for numbers that are supposed to be stored in the empty list I created(and breaks when the user specifies) but it doesnt store these numbers.

It only just stores the last input number.

I have spent a good while trying to figure this on my own but I can't.

I need help with this please!

```
def graph(chi):
    for a in numbers:
        print(num, ". -›", "α" * num)

numbers = [" "]

while True:
    n = 0
    num = int(input("enter a number  "))
    numbers[n] = num
    n +=1
    if True:
        another = input("add another? (y/n) ")
    if another == "y":
        continue
    else:   
        break

#print(numbers)

graph(numbers)
```

Comment: If you post a [mcve] of your code, someone might be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks.. I have done that

Comment: Sorry.. I didnt know. I have indented.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while True:
    n = 0
    num = int(input("enter a number  "))
    numbers[n] = num
    n += 1
```

You are always assigning to `numbers[0]`, because you set `n` to zero at the top of your loop.

If you want to add an element to a list, you should be using [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
numbers = []
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    numbers.append(num)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I understand now.  I have tried it the way you suggested and it worked!  Thanks again.